# Release AVAudioPlayer in iOS4/iOS5 giving EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

**EDIT**: Updated my device (and deployment target) from iOS 4.3.5 to iOS 5.1.1 and still has the same issue

Having a problem releasing a class member **AVAudioPlayer** to play another sound after playing a sound.

This only seems to be a problem on one of my devices, a **3rd** generation **iPod Touch** running **iOS 4.3.5/5.1.1**.

My **4th** and **5th** generation devices running **iOS 6** run just fine.

```
[audio release];
audio = nil;
@try
{
    audio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    if ((audio != nil) && (!error))
    {
        audio.delegate = (id)self;
        audio.volume = gVolume/10;
        [audio play];
    }
    else
    {
        [audio release];
        audio = nil;
    }
}
@catch (NSException *exception)
{
    [audio release];
    audio = nil;
}
```

First time through it plays just fine, but when this code executes a second time to play another sound, it gives an **EXC_BAD_ACCESS** error, which does not happen on my **4th/5th** generation devices.

I purposely delay the **release** until I need to play another sound in order to give the **play** time to perform.

Tried working with **AVAudioPlayerDelegate** but that didn't solve the problem, nor does calling:

```
[audio prepareToPlay];
```

I do initialize **audio** to **nil** in **viewDidLoad**, and clean up in **viewDidUnload** and **dealloc**.

Was having a lot of memory leak issues  but this version of the code seemed to have solved that.

Comment: Why not turn on ARC and make life easier for you?  If you can't turn on ARC, could you run this in Xcode Instruments?

Comment: Mostly because of my ignorance. Not exactly sure how to go about incorporating ARC into an existing app, but it is definitely on the short list of things to look into. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment above, and the failure of all my other ideas, I went ahead and took advantage of **ARC**.

I didn't want to refactor my entire project to start using **ARC**, so I rewrote a new class to handle all of my audio needs and set some compiler flags (**-fobjc-arc**) to enable **ARC** just for that file.

Not exactly sure what I was doing wrong before, but the system seems to be much better at managing memory than I am, and I'm happy to let it solve all my problems.

**EDIT 2**:

Apparently Apple did finally fix their memory leak so I went back to my **ARC** solution which works fine for both **iOS 5** and **iOS 6**.

**EDIT**:

I may have been a little premature.

While implementing **ARC** for this was helpful in general, this specific problem goes deeper.

Apparently, there is a leak in **Core Foundation** for **iOS 6**.

[Leak from NSURL and AVAudioPlayer using ARC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498015/leak-from-nsurl-and-avaudioplayer-using-arc)

[Memory Leak - NSString & NSURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13309745/memory-leak-nsstring-nsurl)

Using **ARC**, it works fine on my **Gen 3 iOS 5** device, but leaks significantly for **Gen 4/5 iOS 6**.

Without **ARC**, **Gen 4/5 iOS 6** works fine, but **Gen 3 iOS 5** crashes.

I ended up making two versions of my new class, one using **ARC** and one not, and checking the system version at runtime **[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]** to determine which version to use.

It may be a little clumsy, but does allow me to support the **Gen 3** devices. If **Apple** ever fixes their problem I can return to a single version at that time.